# Subversion checkout error: Missing update-report close tag

Tags: svn

I get this error every time I try to checkout or update a specific repository from TortoiseSVN:

> Missing update-report close tag

I have absolutely no idea about what I can do to avoid or correct this error.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: what version of svn? where is the repo hosted?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I was able to resolve this issue was by checking out a clean copy of the repository. I isolated the files that were causing the issue, but deleting them and updating simply restored the deleted files.

Checking out a clean copy worked, however.

Answer (score -1):

I ran to into this on version 1.8.1.

I had ignored a subdirectory when it was out of sync and this directory was giving me issues. When I readded everything in the problem directory and commited, I was then able to reignore the directory and update the parent. Hope this helps.